# Экранирование пробельных символов в строке

Tags: javascript

Имею следующий простой тест:

```
const jsObj = {description: `a
b`};
const expected = 'description=a%5Cnb';

const actual = Utils.buildQueryParams(jsObj);

assert.deepEqual(actual, expected);
```

Где-то в недрах `Utils.buildQueryParams` каждый параметр, помещаемый в итоговую строку, проходит следующую процедуру:

```
function encodeQueryItem(item) {
    let escaped = item;
    if (typeof escaped === 'string') {
        escaped = JSON.stringify(escaped);
        escaped = escaped.substring(1, escaped.length - 1);
    }
    return encodeURIComponent(escaped);
}
```

Всё у меня работает как надо, но мне не нравится то, как выглядит `encodeQueryItem`. Можно ли как-то более элегантно это сделать?

---

Раз пошли вопросы «зачем», значит я поясню:
Если у меня строка вида `a\nb`, где `\n` это символ перевода строки, тогда на сервер уйдёт такая строка: `'description=a%0Ab'`, и в этом же виде(после URL decode) там будет сохранена. Потом, когда я его попрошу вернуть мне эту строку, он с радостью положит её в JSON, и JSON парсер сломается, потому что все пробельные символы в строке должны быть экранированы.

Хотя это и не важно, приведу код и `buildQueryParams`:

```
function buildQueryParams(jsObject) {
    return Object.keys(jsObject)
        .map((name) => `${name}=${encodeQueryItem(jsObject[name])}`)
        .join('&');
}
```

Comment: Сам формат - это какой-то костыль. Не надо одновременно два разных экранирования,когда вполне хватает второго.

Comment: Не хватает. Формат должен быть такой как есть. Не ответ на вопрос.

Comment: а я что-то не пойму, зачем мы строке еще раз stringify делаем и судя по всему кавычки обрезаем

Comment: @Grundy, экранирует пробельные символы(\n, \t и т.д)

Comment: @ixSci, но они и через encodeURIComponent умеют экранироваться.

Comment: @Grundy, обновил вопрос.

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, то их можно задать с помощью кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Также, чтобы привлечь больше внимания к вопросу, можно [объявить награду](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/135632)

Comment: @Barmaley, почему не является? И чем это вообще похоже на вопрос?

Comment: Не тянет на ответ, на коммент да, но не на ответ. Коммент мой автосгенерирован из шаблона. Шаблон не очень согласен.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52673/discussion-on-question-by-ixsci-----).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам правильно не нравится как выглядит encodeQueryItem. Потому что encodeURIComponent принимает на вход только строки - а значит, условный оператор тут определенно лишний.

Если задача заключается в том, чтобы закодировать строку так, чтобы сервер не смог ее раскодировать - самым красивым способом будет применить encodeURIComponent дважды:

```
function encodeQueryItem(item) {
  return encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(item));
}
```

Результат encodeURIComponent является "JSON-безопасным", так что проблем с ним не будет. Только надо будет не забыть раскодировать строку обратно на клиенте.

Достоинство этого способа - он не поломается когда сервер все-таки починят.

---

Если же требуется, чтобы сервер выдавал правильно экранированный JSON при неверной реализации - то вы выбрали правильный вариант.

Только проверка типа лишняя, ну и лучше использовать slice как указал lexxl:

```
function encodeQueryItem(item) {
  return encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(item).slice(1, -1));
}
```

Надо помнить, что этот вариант поломается как только сервер починят и будет требовать в дальнейшем довольно странной процедуры декодирования, которой исходно и пытались избежать. А рано или поздно его таки починят, потому что это уязвимость.

---

Если же функция может принимать *разные* типы - надо не забыть, что сервер в любом случае все превратит в строку, а значит - обратного декодирования на клиенте не избежать. Ну и зачем тогда стараться? Просто превращаем все в строку с сохранением типа через stringify - а потом кодируем строку как сделано выше.

Отсутствие отдельной обработки для строк заметно упростит логику декодировщика, который все равно будет.

```
function encodeQueryItemObject(item) {
  return encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(item)));
}
```

*PS вот потому мне и нравится работать фулстеком что можно чинить где поломалось, а не где разрешено :)*